# Beginner OpenGL ES glsurfaceview/Render

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am new to OpenGL and i am trying to learn it. I created a square and i am telling it to rotate. To do that i am telling it to onSurfaceCreated, and it works, it shows the picture rotated. However i read that onSurfaceCreated is called when the surface is created. So the question is, every time that i want to update an object to do any transformation, does it always has to be onSurfaceCreated and if that logic is correct, does that means that every time a new frame is render onSurfaceCreated is called, because by the name onSurfaceCreated and onDraw, i would think that onDraw would do redraw the scene with the updated render of the frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I honestly haven't done this on Android yet, but I've got a good bit of OpenGL ES experience.  But I would think your assumptions are correct.  `onSurfaceCreated` would be an initialization interface that should *not* be called every frame.  Instead you'd be updating and/or redrawing your scene in `onDraw`.

Maybe include some sample code of what you've got so far?  Then we can recommend some ways to architect it a better.

Comment: I have been following this tutorial: [link](http://obviam.net/index.php/texture-mapping-opengl-android-displaying-images-using-opengl-and-squares/) It is pretty much the same expect for a few added stuff like alpha blending. I am messing around with it, to see what it does.

Comment: Ok... so if your code is more or less the same, then it looks as if 'onSurfaceChanged' is just being used to setup the viewport (ie. the area of the surface that will be affected by drawing) and setup a perspective matrix.  The `onDrawFrame` is correctly being used to refresh the scene by clearing the surface and redrawing.

Comment: So what is your actual goal with your project?  What do you want it to do?

Comment: Nothing big, i am trying to grasp the basics here. I just want it move the square from one point to another point within a certain time.

Comment: Ok... well if you look in that `onDrawFrame` function, it is continually updating a matrix every time it enters that function (the 'ModelView' matrix).  In the example, it is setting the matrix to move the square -5.0 units away from the camera.  If you were to change that -5.0 into a variable and update it over time, you would see your square animate.  To move left/right you make a variable for the first 0.0, and up/down the second 0.0.  With those three variables you can start to animate the square in any direction.  That's a good starting point.  :)  Good luck!